# Airflow - Subdag stuck in running state with its internal tasks ended successfully

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer, airflow

we're facing a very strange behavior in Airflow.
Some subdags stuck running (with its internal tasks successfully ended).

For example, I have the subdag *load-folder-to-layer* that should have started and ended in 2020-11-18, but it stuck until 20th.

I looked in the `task_instances` and `job` table and could see that the task's job was executing and receiving heartbeat:
[image: task's job status]

The last log message in the subdag is:

```
[2020-11-18 09:22:01,879] {taskinstance.py:664} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: bietlejuice.docx.load-folder-reference-to-clean 2020-11-17T03:00:00+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
```

Also, I could notice a node drop on the exact same day 18th (image):
[image: workers state]

This leads me to think that the Scheduler is facing a bug when reatributing this task(subdag) to another worker and leading the task to get stuck.

Does someone have a clue about it?

Comment: For this particular issue, I would suggest you to either [opening a Support Case on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) or [creating a Composer Issue in Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460446&template=0). I've already searched in [Airflow's JIRA Issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1965?jql=text%20~%20%22subdag%20stuck%22) as well as in the [List of open Cloud Composer issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5249404) but I didn't find similar reports.

Comment: Preferably, if you have any Support package or plan, I would go with a Support Case as  troubleshooting this probably requires you to provide as much information as possible and maybe inspect your Composer environment. If you don't have one, creating a Public Issue is also a good option.